# How to Plot few line graphs for similar values in x axis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have this dataframe; which contains processed data from a video using a facial recognition system. I wanted to plot the variation of age, emotions and gender with the frames.

[image]

i tried to plot emotions vs frame graph using below

```
dict_emo = df.set_index('Frame').to_dict()['Emotion']
x = np.array(list(zip(*dict_emo.items())))
u, ind = np.unique(x[1,:], return_inverse=True)
x[1,:] = ind

u, ind = np.unique(x[1,:], return_inverse=True)
x[1,:] = ind
x = x.astype(int).T
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

plt.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1])

plt.gca().set_yticks(range(len(u)))
plt.title("Variation of Emotions in Frames")
plt.xlabel("Frame")
plt.ylabel("Emotion")
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['Angry', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Neutral', 'Sad'])
plt.tick_params(labelsize=10)
plt.show()
```

and i got a graph like this. But there can be more than one face in a single frame so there are multiple records for some same frames ex: row(343,344) in the dataframe since this needs to modified. I want such faces to be plotted with a diffrent color line the same graph. Any idea on how this can be done?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A lineplot seems unadapted to your use case. You can keep track of all your parameters with `seaborn.scatterplot`, using different colors for `Gender` and sizes for `Age` for instance:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Frame', y='Emotion', hue='Gender', size='Age')
plt.show()
```

Output (with dummy data):

[image]

Edit/Update: the above plot might be hard to read because of the overlay of multiple dots. A [swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) could be preferable, however since those do not accept the kwarg `size`, you should do it with seaborn [object API](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface):

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
(
  so.Plot(data=df, x='Frame', y='Emotion', color='Gender', pointsize='Age')
  .add(so.Dots(), so.Jitter(0.6))
  .on(ax).plot()
)
# since seaborn object API doesn't allow legend positioning, you can drag the legend where it suits you:
for leg in fig.legends:
    leg.set(draggable=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]